# About grapes (виноград) and grapes (винограды)

Tags: узус

I understand that in Russian, виноград is a collective noun implying the plural “grapes”. However, when looking into it in Wikislovar (https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4), it also has a plural form винограды.

My question is the following: in which circumstances will its plural form (винограды) be used and what would be its difference in meaning?

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you've seen "винограды"?

Comment: Ok, I've found it: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/виноград , but it sounds very strange to my ear... I would not say there is any situation when you would use it, except maybe for some professional jargon.

Comment: Ruscorpora lists [only 24 usages](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=винограды) of the word "винограды", while more that 1000 for "виноград". I'd say that "винограды" is very rare and dated and maybe poetic.

Comment: "Винограды" is not a word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Виноград* can be used in plural in these cases:

1. When talking about many different varieties of grapes (this also works with any other mass noun). Usually it's conveyed analytically (using *сорта винограда* and similar) but the plural can be used as well:

> - Лучшие винограды Абхазии созревают в ваших виноградниках.
> - Богатство родины было представлено белой рыбой и красной рыбой, горками икр обоего цвета, кулебяками, печеными пирожками, выпечкой с вязигой, венгерскими вольноотпущенными индейками, валдайскими поросятами, напоминающими кое-кого из зала, винами из личного погреба далеко еще не забытого византийца (дали умереть, а «Киндзмараули» утащили), виноградами из его родной Картли; и только цитрусы были привозные ― большие поставки из Яффы через Дальний Восток

2. When used in the original Church Slavonic sense of "vineyard". This usage is dated, but can be used for stylistic purposes:

> - «Дай вам, говорит, гору золотую, реку медвяную, сады-винограды, яблони кудрявы; будете сыты да пьяны, будете обуты-одеты!»
> - Сады, сельские домики, луга и винограды представились глазам моим.
> - Коль пойду в сады али в винограды

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary provides all possible word forms, which, being grammatically correct are not necessarily widely use or make sense. "Винограды" is a correct form, just like, say, "сметаны" or "человечества", but you indeed won't find this form in active usage. If we are talking specifically about grape as a single instance of a berry (well, most likely it's not the correct scientific term but you got the idea) - it's "виноградина", with plural "виноградины".

However, for the sake of exercise, one can still come up with a sentence which intentionally contains word "винограды". Or, even, more you can even google one, like folliwng:

> Самые ранние винограды растут в Хатлонской области Таджикистана под
> названием «Гиссарские ранние» которые созревают в середине май месяца.